# CakePHP : Object of class Laminas\Diactoros\UploadedFile could not be converted to string while file upload

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I am trying to upload file in cakephp version 4.

I am following this [docs](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/request-response.html#file-uploads)

I have tried in controller

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            $image = $this->request->getData('image');
            $fileName = $image->getClientFilename();

            $targetPath = WWW_ROOT.'img'.DS.$fileName;

            $image->moveTo($targetPath);

            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());   //line 58

            $user->image = $fileName;

            $this->Users->save($user);
}
```

Image upload is working fine, name also saving in database. But when a validation error occur I am getting

```
Warning (4096): Object of class Laminas\Diactoros\UploadedFile could not be converted to string [CORE\src\Database\Type\StringType.php, line 97]
```

logs

```
Cake\Database\Type\StringType::marshal() - CORE\src\Database\Type\StringType.php, line 97
Cake\ORM\Marshaller::Cake\ORM\{closure}() - CORE\src\ORM\Marshaller.php, line 78
Cake\ORM\Marshaller::merge() - CORE\src\ORM\Marshaller.php, line 558
Cake\ORM\Table::patchEntity() - CORE\src\ORM\Table.php, line 2761
App\Controller\UsersController::add() - APP/Controller\UsersController.php, line 58
Cake\Controller\Controller::invokeAction() - CORE\src\Controller\Controller.php, line 524
Cake\Controller\ControllerFactory::invoke() - CORE\src\Controller\ControllerFactory.php, line 79
Cake\Http\BaseApplication::handle() - CORE\src\Http\BaseApplication.php, line 229
Cake\Http\Runner::handle() - CORE\src\Http\Runner.php, line 77
Cake\Http\Runner::handle() - CORE\src\Http\Runner.php, line 77
Cake\Http\Middleware\CsrfProtectionMiddleware::process() - CORE\src\Http\Middleware\CsrfProtectionMiddleware.php, line 132
Cake\Http\Runner::handle() - CORE\src\Http\Runner.php, line 73
Cake\Http\Runner::run() - CORE\src\Http\Runner.php, line 58
Cake\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware::process() - CORE\src\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware.php, line 162
Cake\Http\Runner::handle() - CORE\src\Http\Runner.php, line 73
Cake\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware::process() - CORE\src\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware.php, line 68
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, your code example blindly trusts the client, it accepts any file, and allows to choose arbitrary target locations by passing a path as the filename! Never use client data without validating/sanitizing it, trusting the file date provided by the client can lead to all sorts of vulnerabilities!!!

That being said, usually you either use a separate field for the file upload, or a custom database type that doesn't transform the data when it is being marshalled, so that you can transform it manually afterwards. Currently you seem to use the field for the upload that is supposed to hold a string in the database, hence the marshaller will try to convert the input to a string, and that will of course fail.

So for example, rename the form control from `image` to `image_file` (no such column should exist in the database), add proper validation rules for `image_file`, something along the lines of this, to ensure that the upload is valid, ie check the type, the size, the name, etc:

```php
$validator
    ->notEmptyFile('image_file')
    ->uploadedFile('image_file', [
        'types' => ['image/png'], // only PNG image files
        'minSize' => 1024, // Min 1 KB
        'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024 // Max 1 MB
    ])
    ->add('image_file', 'minSize', [
        'rule' => ['imageSize', [
            // Min 10x10 pixel
            'width' => [Validation::COMPARE_GREATER_OR_EQUAL, 10],
            'height' => [Validation::COMPARE_GREATER_OR_EQUAL, 10],
        ]]
    ])
    ->add('image_file', 'maxSize', [
        'rule' => ['imageSize', [
            // Max 100x100 pixel
            'width' => [Validation::COMPARE_LESS_OR_EQUAL, 100],
            'height' => [Validation::COMPARE_LESS_OR_EQUAL, 100],
        ]]
    ])
    ->add('image_file', 'filename', [
        'rule' => function (UploadedFileInterface $file) {
            // filename must not be a path
            $filename = $file->getClientFilename();
            if (strcmp(basename($filename), $filename) === 0) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    ])
    ->add('image_file', 'extension', [
        'rule' => ['extension', ['png']] // .png file extension only
    ]);
```

And then handle the upload *after* patching, ie after validation has taken place, and only move the file if validation was successful!

```php
$user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());
if (!$user->getErrors()) {
    // never trust anything in `$image` if you haven't properly validated it!!!
    $image = $this->request->getData('image_file');
    $fileName = $image->getClientFilename();
    // if you want to take it a step further, drop the user supplied filename
    // $fileName = \Cake\Utility\Security::hash($image->getClientFilename(), 'sha1');
    // and re-encode the image to remove possible dangerous payloads, meta data, etc
    // reEncodeImage($image->getStream());

    $image->moveTo(WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS . $fileName);

    $user->image = $fileName;
}

if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
    // success
} else {
    // failure
}
```

Once you've got a grip on how things work, you should probably consider moving the upload handling logic in your table class or a behavior (the `beforeSave()` event/callback is very popular for executing upload logic), or some kind of service.

You may also want to have a look at how existing plugins are handling uploads, see for example **https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/awesome-cakephp#user-content-files**

Comment: HI @ndm , I have added validation allowEmptyFile('image-name'), Then I am getting same warning. If I want to save my data without file then how can I manage it ? Would you please help me on this issue ? If I upload image then everything working fine. I am getting warning in patchEntity method.

Comment: @NiloyRony That's a very different problem, so I'd suggest to create a new question where you can properly elaborate on the problem, and show all of your new code. That makes answering easier, and it also helps future readers with the same problem to find the answer.

Comment: @Dave The alias for a rule can be arbitrary, it should not affect how a rule works. If `minImageSize` doesn't work for you, but `minSize` does, then you likely have a problem somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @ndm it seems minSize is built in to Cake.  Certainly possible that something wrong on my end, but I'm quite close to a fresh install.

Comment: @Dave There is no `minSize` rule in the core, but even if there were, it wouldn't interfere with aliases. The actual rule that is being used there is `imageSize`, the rule alias only defines what key is being used for the possible error message in the validation results, other than that it has no purpose, eg you could name it `horseFizzlePopSticks` and it would behave exactly the same with regards to validation as if you've named it `minSize`.

Comment: @ndm ah, I understand.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

```
// add
public function add()
{
    $info = $this->Infos->newEmptyEntity();           //debug($info);
    $this->Authorization->authorize($info);           

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $data       = $this->request->getData();                 //debug($data);
        $dimage     = $this->request->getData('image');                 

        $name       = $dimage->getClientFilename();              //debug($name);
        $type       = $dimage->getClientMediaType();             //debug($type);           
        $size       = $dimage->getSize();                        //debug($size);
        $tmpName    = $dimage->getStream()->getMetadata('uri');  //debug($tmpName);
        $error      = $dimage->getError();                       //debug($error); 
        
        $targetPath = WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS . 'infos' . DS . $name;  //debug($targetPath); 

        if ($type == 'image/jpeg' || $type == 'image/jpg'  || $type == 'image/png') {
            if (!empty($name)) {
                if ( ($size > 0) && ($size < 1048576) && ($error == 0)) {    // less 1MB    
                    $dimage->moveTo($targetPath);     
                }
            }
        } 

        $data['image'] = $name;  //debug($info); //debug($data);
        $info          = $this->Infos->patchEntity($info, $data);        
        $info->user_id = $this->request->getAttribute('identity')->getIdentifier();        

        if ($this->Infos->save($info)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The info has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Infos', 'action' => 'view', $info->id]);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The info could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            return $this->redirect(['controller'=>'Infos', 'action' => 'add']);
        }    
    }
    
    $infoCategories = $this->Infos->InfoCategories->find('list', ['limit' => 200])->all();
    $this->set(compact('info','infoCategories'));
}
```