# Cakephp error on upload adding file to table Object of class Laminas\Diactoros\UploadedFile

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have an small upload script and I have follwed a tutorial, docs and a similar issue in this post [CakePHP : Object of class Laminas\Diactoros\UploadedFile could not be converted to string while file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60755872/cakephp-object-of-class-laminas-diactoros-uploadedfile-could-not-be-converted) but I get the same error. The upload worked fine before I added the upload validation rules.

Error

```
Object of class Laminas\Diactoros\UploadedFile could not be converted to string
```

strategies add.php

```
<?= $this->Form->control('strategies_screenshots.0.image_file', ['type' => 'file']); ?>
```

StrategiesController

```
public function add()
{
    $strategy = $this->Strategies->newEmptyEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $strategy = $this->Strategies->patchEntity($strategy, $this->request->getData());

        if(!$strategy-getErrors) {
            $image = $this->request->getData('strategies_screenshots.0.image_file');
            $fileName = $image->getClientFilename();

            $targetPath = WWW_ROOT.'screenshots'.DS.$fileName;

            if($image_name)
            $image->moveTo($targetPath);

            $strategy['strategies_screenshots'][0]['image_name'] = $fileName;
        }

        if ($this->Strategies->save($strategy)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The strategy has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The strategy could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    $users = $this->Strategies->Users->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('strategy', 'users'));
}
```

StrategiesScreenshotsTable

```
$validator
    ->notEmptyFile('image_file')
    ->uploadedFile('image_file', [
        'types' => ['image/png'], // only PNG image files
        'minSize' => 1024, // Min 1 KB
        'maxSize' => 10240 * 1024 // Max 10 MB
    ])
    ->add('image_file', 'filename', [
        'rule' => function (UploadedFileInterface $file) {
            // filename must not be a path
            $filename = $file->getClientFilename();
            if (strcmp(basename($filename), $filename) === 0) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    ])
    ->add('image_file', 'extension', [
        'rule' => ['extension', ['png']] // .png file extension only
    ]);
```

Detailled error:

```
[Error] Object of class Laminas\Diactoros\UploadedFile could not be converted to string in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trading-journal/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Type/StringType.php on line 97 
Stack Trace: - /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trading-journal/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Marshaller.php:78 
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trading-journal/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Marshaller.php:210 
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trading-journal/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Marshaller.php:363 
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trading-journal/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Marshaller.php:332 
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trading-journal/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Marshaller.php:735 
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trading-journal/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Marshaller.php:115 
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trading-journal/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Marshaller.php:566 
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trading-journal/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Table.php:2795 
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trading-journal/src/Controller/StrategiesController.php:54 
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trading-journal/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Controller.php:521 
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trading-journal/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/ControllerFactory.php:79 
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trading-journal/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/BaseApplication.php:229 
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trading-journal/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:77 
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trading-journal/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Middleware/BodyParserMiddleware.php:164 
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trading-journal/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73 
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trading-journal/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:77 
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trading-journal/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Middleware/CsrfProtectionMiddleware.php:138 
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trading-journal/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73 
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trading-journal/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:58 
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trading-journal/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/RoutingMiddleware.php:166 
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trading-journal/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73 
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trading-journal/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/AssetMiddleware.php:68 
 - /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trading-journal/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73 
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trading-journal/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Middleware/ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php:119 
 - /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trading-journal/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73 
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trading-journal/vendor/cakephp/debug_kit/src/Middleware/DebugKitMiddleware.php:60 
- /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trading-journal/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73 
 - /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trading-journal/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:58 
 - /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trading-journal/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Server.php:90 
 - /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trading-journal/webroot/index.php:40
 Request URL: /strategies/add Referer URL: http://localhost:8888/trading-journal/strategies/add
```

Output of `debug($this->request->getData());`

```
/src/Controller/StrategiesController.php (line 54)
[
    'user_id' => '1',
    'name' => 'sdf',
    'description' => '',
    'strategies_screenshots' => [
        (int) 0 => [
            'image_file' => object(Laminas\Diactoros\UploadedFile) {
                [private] clientFilename => 'Screen Shot 2020-04-15 at 10.11.59.png'
                [private] clientMediaType => 'image/png'
                [private] error => (int) 0
                [private] file => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpbwWNVX'
                [private] moved => false
                [private] size => (int) 348653
                [private] stream => null
            }
        ]
    ]
]
```

I have also tried:

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator): Validator
{
    $validator
        ->integer('id')
        ->allowEmptyString('id', null, 'create');

        $validator
        ->allowEmptyFile('image_name')
        ->add( 'image_name', [
        'mimeType' => [
            'rule' => [ 'mimeType', [ 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/jpeg' ] ],
            'message' => 'Please upload only jpg and png.',
        ],
        'fileSize' => [
            'rule' => [ 'fileSize', '<=', '10MB' ],
            'message' => 'Image file size must be less than 1MB.',
        ],
    ] );
```

When I run the following I have no issue:

```
    $validator
        ->scalar('image_name')
        ->maxLength('image_name', 100)
        ->requirePresence('image_name', 'create')
        ->notEmptyFile('image_name');
```

Comment: When you receive errors, please always post the complete error message (include file name and line number), and also include the related stacktrace!

Comment: I have updated the error

Comment: In your data the field is named `image_name`, but according to your code, that is the string type field in your database, and the controller expects the uploaded file in the field named `image_file`.

Comment: from the last stackoverflow question it suggested changing the name of the form to something different to the field name. I had everything all set `image_name` and the same error. I have just changed back agin to `image_name` and yes exact same error

Comment: I guess one of the `image_name`'s in your comment is supposed to be `image_file`? In any case, everything should use `image_file` except for that one line in your controller that populates `image_name` with the final path of the stored file. From your debug output, you were still using `image_name` in your form.

Comment: yes that is what I have in posted code. I use `image_file` everywhere except for `$strategy['strategies_screenshots'][0]['image_name'] = $fileName;` The occurs with the `$strategy = $this->Strategies->patchEntity($strategy, $this->request->getData());`

Comment: But not in your form, at least according to your debug output. So right now we're at the point where I don't know what your code actually looks like. According to the marshaller there's apparently a field in your form data that matches a field in your database schema.

Comment: I have updated the question to where all the code is using `image_file`

Comment: I have done a clean install of CakePHP and added back the upload code. All working fine now as expected. No errors. The only thing that I could think of was I had installed a couple of plugins.

Comment: A cached schema could be a possible source for the problem, as the schemas column type is used to determine how to cast a fields value, ie maybe you've changed the column name in the schema without clearing the schema cache afterwards.