# How to solve the CakePHP warning message "Object of class Laminas\Diactoros\UploadedFile could not be converted to string"?

Tags: php, image, cakephp, laminas-api-tools

The submission will be added to the database and the images will be uploaded to the img and img2 folders. However, if the submission is successful, I still get the warning message "Object of class Laminas\Diactoros\UploadedFile could not be converted to string". I am stuck on how to hide the warning message or solve the warning message. I have image validation and I am not sure why that doesn't resolve the warning message. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated. A similar Stack Overflow question helped me make progress on this problem, but I still haven't found a solid solution.

The controller file is how the images are uploaded to the img and img2 folders. It is how the submission is posted to the database.
(SubmissionsController.php)

```
$submission = $this->Submissions->newEmptyEntity();
            if ($this->request->is('post')) {

                $submission = $this->Submissions->patchEntity($submission, $this->request->getData());

                if(!$submission->getErrors()) {
                    $image  = $this->request->getData('image_path');
                    $name   = $image->getClientFilename();
                    $image->moveTo(WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS . $name);
                    $submission->image_path = $name;

                    $image2 = $this->request->getData('image_path2');
                    $name2  = $image2->getClientFilename();
                    $image2->moveTo(WWW_ROOT . 'img2' . DS . $name2);
                    $submission->image_path2 = $name2;
                }

                if($this->Submissions->save($submission)) {
                    if($this->Auth->user('UserGroupID') == 3 || $this->Auth->user('UserGroupID') == 2) {
                        $this->Flash->success(__('The submission has been saved.'));
                        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
                    } else {
                        $this->Flash->success(__('The submission has been saved.'));
                        return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'ModelTypes', 'action' => 'index'));
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->Flash->error(__('The submission could not be saved. Make sure that the file is an image with these file extensions (jpg, jpeg, png).'));
                }
            }
```

The table file is where the image field validation takes place. I think this is where code needs to go to solve the warning message.
(SubmissionsTable.php)

```
       $validator
            ->notEmptyFile('image_path')
            ->uploadedFile('image_path', [
                'types' => ['image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/jpeg'],
                'minSize' => 1024, // Min 1 KB
                'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024 // Max 1 MB
            ])
            ->add('image_path', [
                'mimeType' => [
                    'rule' => [ 'mimeType', [ 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/jpeg' ] ],
                    'message' => 'Please upload only jpg, jpeg, and png.',
                ],
                'fileSize' => [
                    'rule' => [ 'fileSize', '<=', '1MB' ],
                    'message' => 'Image file size must be less than 1MB.',
                ]
            ])
            ->add('image_path', 'filename', [
                'rule' => function (UploadedFileInterface $file) {
                    // filename must not be a path
                    $filename = $file->getClientFilename();
                    if (strcmp(basename($filename), $filename) === 0) {
                        return true;
                    }
        
                    return false;
                }
            ])
            ->add('image_path', 'extension', [
                'rule' => ['extension', ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg']]
            ]);
       $validator
            ->notEmptyFile('image_path2')
            ->uploadedFile('image_path2', [
                'types' => ['image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/jpeg'],
                'minSize' => 1024, // Min 1 KB
                'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024 // Max 1 MB
            ])
            ->add('image_path2', [
                'mimeType' => [
                    'rule' => [ 'mimeType', [ 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/jpeg' ] ],
                    'message' => 'Please upload only jpg, jpeg, and png.',
                ],
                'fileSize' => [
                    'rule' => [ 'fileSize', '<=', '1MB' ],
                    'message' => 'Image file size must be less than 1MB.',
                ]
            ])
            ->add('image_path2', 'filename', [
                'rule' => function (UploadedFileInterface $file) {
                    // filename must not be a path
                    $filename = $file->getClientFilename();
                    if (strcmp(basename($filename), $filename) === 0) {
                        return true;
                    }
        
                    return false;
                }
            ])
            ->add('image_path2', 'extension', [
                'rule' => ['extension', ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg']]
            ]);
```

These are the two image form fields.
(add.php)

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 mt-3">
            <?php
                echo $this->Form->control('image_path', array('type' => 'file'));
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 mt-3">
            <?php
                echo $this->Form->control('image_path2', array('type' => 'file'));
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Error Message:

```
Warning (4096): Object of class Laminas\Diactoros\UploadedFile could not be converted to string [CORE\src\Database\Type\StringType.php, line 97]
Cake\Database\Type\StringType::marshal() - CORE\src\Database\Type\StringType.php, line 97
Cake\ORM\Marshaller::Cake\ORM\{closure}() - CORE\src\ORM\Marshaller.php, line 78
Cake\ORM\Marshaller::merge() - CORE\src\ORM\Marshaller.php, line 566
Cake\ORM\Table::patchEntity() - CORE\src\ORM\Table.php, line 2795
App\Controller\SubmissionsController::add() - APP/Controller\SubmissionsController.php, line 37
Cake\Controller\Controller::invokeAction() - CORE\src\Controller\Controller.php, line 521
Cake\Controller\ControllerFactory::invoke() - CORE\src\Controller\ControllerFactory.php, line 79
Cake\Http\BaseApplication::handle() - CORE\src\Http\BaseApplication.php, line 229
Cake\Http\Runner::handle() - CORE\src\Http\Runner.php, line 77
Cake\Http\Middleware\BodyParserMiddleware::process() - CORE\src\Http\Middleware\BodyParserMiddleware.php, line 164
Cake\Http\Runner::handle() - CORE\src\Http\Runner.php, line 73
Cake\Http\Runner::handle() - CORE\src\Http\Runner.php, line 77
Cake\Http\Middleware\CsrfProtectionMiddleware::process() - CORE\src\Http\Middleware\CsrfProtectionMiddleware.php, line 138
Cake\Http\Runner::handle() - CORE\src\Http\Runner.php, line 73
Cake\Http\Runner::run() - CORE\src\Http\Runner.php, line 58
Cake\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware::process() - CORE\src\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware.php, line 166
```

It looks like the error is being thrown on this line:

```
$submission = $this->Submissions->patchEntity($submission, $this->request->getData());
```

Comment: It should tell you exactly what line that warning is coming from. It would be very useful to know what code that refers to.

Comment: I added the actual error message with the lines of code. Does that help?

Comment: You've missed the point of [**the answer for that other question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60755872/cakephp-object-of-class-laminas-diactoros-uploadedfile-could-not-be-converted/60757604#60757604) where you got this from, your form control name for the upload should be different to your database/entity field name that is supposed to the store the file path!

Comment: Thank you 'ndm'. I changed image_path to image_file and it appears that the warning message does not show up on successful submission. The reason that I didn't try changing the form control name to a name different from the database field name before is that it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Well, it is required because when you patch the entity, the marshaller will convert the passed data according to the database type of the respective fields, so for your string type `image_path` column, the value will be converted to a string, but it holds an uploaded file object, which cannot (and should not) be converted to a string, hence the error. You side step this by using a different name that isn't mapped to a database type, so that the marshaller will directly set it on the entity without trying to convert the value.

Comment: Thank you ndm for the explanation. That does make a lot more sense to me now.